# .htaccess password protection doesn't work (redirects to 404)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, passwords, http-status-code-404

In my public folder, I have a logs folder which I want to protect using a .htpasswd. My app folder is actually inside public (the site is built with that in mind and it wouldn't be worth moving app). When I try to access the password protected folder, it just redirects me to a 404. If I take out the MVC rewriting part, it works. This is my directory structure, in case it helps.

```
root/
  public/
    app/
      start.php
      .htaccess
      ...
    logs/
      .htaccess
      .htpasswd
      errorlog.md
    index.php
    .htaccess
  vendor/
```

This is the part of the .htaccess in /public that I think matters.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cfnw-user [NC]
    RewriteRule ^resources/newspaper http://example.com/error/401 [NC,L]

    # Force to exclude the trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=307,L]

    # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess in /logs.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Log files. Sensitive information."
AuthUserFile /home/site/public/logs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I'm wondering how I can make the password protection work without redirecting to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess in `/public` folder, you have removed autoindexing with `Options -Indexes`. This is valid for all subfolders unless you change it again. Because of this, when a visitor arrives in the folder `/logs`,  there is no index.html or index.php file, and autoindexing is deactivated, so there is nothing for Apache to show. AFAIK you should have a "403 Forbidden" error, and not the 404 Not found.

So put in the .htaccess file in `public/logs` folder

`Options +Indexes`

and check if you have mod_autoindex loaded/enabled.

Comment: Nope, still 404s even with that. It doesn't matter if I go to /logs or /logs/errorlog.md. Still the same.

Comment: @Telinc1 Then the problem may be somewhere else. Try to have a look at error logs, and if you can, trun on mod_rewrite logging (you need access to server config files for this) and see what it says. I tested your setup and your rules here and it works as expected, with the two steps mentionned in this answer.

Comment: I don't have access to the server config files. This probably a very weird thing that happens only on my server, don't know why though.